# node.js client's requests are being broken(timeout over), but still works on my server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a API server using node.js

My server is connected to a large number of clients.

Because of this, the server's response time is increased.

So Client disconnected before receiving the response

but still processing the server(for client request).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please, clarify how long does it take to process a single request and how many clients are connected when this issue starts to arise?

Comment: my client require 1000m/s. but my server response's time about 2000m/s. However, the important thing is that the client do not know that I will be treated.

Comment: Well.. First you need to find the reason why your server processes request 2 seconds (it's **very** long). Make sure you have no 'blocking' code such as `fs.readFileSync`. Also, Node is not a great fit for heavy calculations. Or may be, you just need to upgrade your server. If you find it impossible to speed up the server, then try to employ some task scheduling. So that client sends first request and starts the job and after a 2 second timeout repeats it to take result. It's the only help you get there with such an ambiguous question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. 
I can upgrade my server. And the algorithm can be improved. 

But the fact that I do not want to miss include: 

Simple explanation. 
client is sending data to the server to store the data (database)

Comment: If they are stored in the database, the server notifies the client 

The problem occurs in the following situations:. 
Users will connect to the server suddenly(many many!). As a result, the response time is increased.


If the response speed is slow, the customer's request, the connection is dropped due to timeout 
However, it is true my server that it has to process client's request that has been cut out. 
The fact that the process, it is within the customer does not know, this is my system is a large-scale disaster.

Comment: so i study..connect-timeout module...but This does not work correctly.